# Using grepl to match character in a string of characters with delimiters

Tags: r

There are a number of solutions for using `grepl()`, but none which solves my problem (that I have come across so far). I have two data frames. The first labelled `x` containing a set of combinations associated with a letter:

```
structure(list(variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), combinations = c("16, 17, 18", 
"17,18", "16,18", "12,3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

> x
  variable combinations
1        A   16, 17, 18
2        B        17,18
3        C        16,18
4        D         12,3
```

The second data frame is the results. It is a set of observations showing the letters that a species interacted with. Below is just one set of observations:

```
structure(list(variable = c("A, C", NA, NA), species = c("16", 
"17", "18"), active = c("16", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

> y
  variable species active
1     A, C      16     16
2     <NA>      17   <NA>
3     <NA>      18   <NA>
```

This was the original structure of `y`:

```
> y
  variable species.active species.present
1     A, C             16           17,18
```

The structure was changed to add more columns associated to each species (so each species had a row), thus the structure serves a specific purpose.

What I want is to have a binary column (T/F or 0/1) to show whether or not each species are in the combinations associated with the variable.

This is what I have managed so far:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
#carry locf so that each species are assigned the same variables 
y <- y %>% 
  mutate(variable = zoo::na.locf(variable))

#separate each row to separate combinations 
library(tidyr)
y <- separate_rows(y, variable)

#match x$variable by y$variable to add associated combinations in a new column in y
y$combinations <- ifelse(y$variable %in% x$variable, x$combinations)

#return true or false if each species is in the combination
y$type <- grepl(y$species, y$combinations);y

> y
variable species active combinations type 
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>        <lgl>
1 A        16      16     16, 17, 18   TRUE 
2 C        16      16     17,18        FALSE
3 A        17      NA     16,18        TRUE 
4 C        17      NA     12,3         FALSE
5 A        18      NA     16, 17, 18   TRUE 
6 C        18      NA     17,18        FALSE
```

As you can see, the combinations are wrong and the `gprel()` returns incorrect T/F (refer to row 3 where it says it is true but '17' is not in the combination anyway.

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please specify your actual expected output, what should `type` really be? I'm thinking T,F,F,F,T,T?

Comment: The expected output is shown in the last data frame above, where y has two new columns: combinations and type.  Type should be returning the correct true or false (it can be any type of binary output) based on the combinations column. But both columns are incorrect.

Comment: "Warning message:
In grepl(y$species, y$combinations) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: Your `ifelse` is broken, it needs a `no=` argument (even if it isn't used in this sample).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, choosing one of `type1` or `type2` (same result), whichever you prefer.

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(y, x, by = "variable") %>%
  mutate(
    type1 = mapply(`%in%`, species, strsplit(combinations, "\\D+")),
    type2 = mapply(grepl, paste0("\\b", species, "\\b"), combinations)
  )
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   variable species active combinations type1 type2
#   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>        <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 A        16      16     16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 2 C        16      16     16,18        TRUE  TRUE 
# 3 A        17      <NA>   16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 4 C        17      <NA>   16,18        FALSE FALSE
# 5 A        18      <NA>   16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 6 C        18      <NA>   16,18        TRUE  TRUE
```

Or starting with the *original* `y`:

```r
y
#   variable species active
# 1     A, C      16     16
# 2     <NA>      17   <NA>
# 3     <NA>      18   <NA>

y %>%
  mutate(variable = zoo::na.locf(variable)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(variable) %>%
  left_join(., x, by = "variable") %>%
  mutate(type1 = mapply(`%in%`, species, strsplit(combinations, "\\D+")), type2 = mapply(grepl, paste0("\\b", species, "\\b"), combinations))
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   variable species active combinations type1 type2
#   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <chr>        <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 A        16      16     16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 2 C        16      16     16,18        TRUE  TRUE 
# 3 A        17      <NA>   16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 4 C        17      <NA>   16,18        FALSE FALSE
# 5 A        18      <NA>   16, 17, 18   TRUE  TRUE 
# 6 C        18      <NA>   16,18        TRUE  TRUE
```

FYI, some things wrong with your question:

1. When asking questions that include warnings or errors, you need to include them; in this case, `grepl`'s first argument must be length 1, and it appears you are ignoring it:

   ```r
   grepl(y$species, y$combinations)
   # Warning in grepl(y$species, y$combinations) :
   #   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
   ```
2. `ifelse` in your code seems to work, but you are using it incorrectly: it requires a `no=` argument as well, so there needs to be something as its third argument. It does not error here because everything resolves to be true (which is another problem) so it never attempts to evaluate `no=`.

   ```r
   ifelse(c(T,T), 1:2)
   # [1] 1 2
   ifelse(c(T,F), 1:2)
   # Error in ifelse(c(T, F), 1:2) : argument "no" is missing, with no default
   ifelse(c(T,F), 1:2, 11:12)
   # [1]  1 12
   ```
3. What you're attempting to do is merge/join `x` and `y`, so the tools you want are among `base::merge` and `dplyr::*_join` (for starters, others exist). To better understand what's going on in a join, I suggest you see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.  The combination column is incorrect, is there a solution to fix as well?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, my combinations are wrong to begin with, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: See my edit, I think I've resolved the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I originally had it written in a similar way as the first option , but struggled, so tried to break down each problem I had. Glad that I'm very slowly heading in the write direction! Cheers